# how to clone browser instance in watin

Tags: c#, testing, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, watin

I need to clone the browser instance, In watin IE is shared resource which makes very difficult to store the previous browser instance

```
var browser = new IE(http://www.stackoverflow.com);

var copybrowser = browser;

browser.goto("http://www.superuser.com");

console.WriteLine(browser.Uri);
console.WriteLine(copybrowser.Uri);

output:
http://www.superuser.com
http://www.superuser.com
```

In this case i need to store the previous instance, i have seen clone method in watin, but i was  unable to recall, does any one how to solve this problem, i need to get the previous instance of browser

Comment: In your case, `copybrowser` is only a _reference_ to the same object as `browser` is pointing to, so those are obviously the same. I'm not even sure it is possible to create a clone of an existing browser instance in WatiN, because when you do `new IE(...)` it will fire up a whole new instance, and it would be quite a hassle to "copy" all the state of your existing browser instance (you might have navigated somewhere, filled out lots of form fields etc). But more interesting: _why_ do you want to do this? It sounds more like you might be trying to solve a problem in the wrong way...

Comment: may be i am doing it in wrong way... but i would actually need that methodology...even now i did not find any correct approach.....

Comment: When you say _"but i would actually need that methodology"_, you ought to explain to us _why_. As I said, it sounds like you might be trying to solve a probme in the wrong way (or even the wrong problem): if you explain what you're trying to do, there might be somebody able to suggest to you an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a class with browser property

```
public class Session
{
    public Browser browser { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
}
```

In this case you can create multiple Session instances when each instance has his own browser instance.

Comment: may be i need to do more research on the above stated method... i will give a try... and let you know